# Is it possible to let android studio read resources in external folder with sourceSets?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Here is sample of sourceSets code block in build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
```

What I wanted to achieve is that. I want it read resources from external folder. As example in `data/data/com.myapp/res`.

Im not good with gradle API, can someone guide me of how to do it?

The reason I want to do like this is because. My client want to update string translation dynamically. Without the need to re-compile and re-download the app. I know this is not the standard way of using the multilanguage. But I don't want to turn their requirement down without effort and strong evidence.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `sourceSets`.

Source set is basically used to map source folders in your project. It is not a means to point to directories in the installed app.

**Update after reading the reason:**

Since you only want to deal with strings, the easiest way would be to store them in a sqlite db and then update the db from server whenever required with the new values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But do you know any alternative to achieve similar result?

Comment: I am failing to understand what you are trying to achieve. Why would you want to put it in an external folder. If you can elaborate on your purpose may be i can suggest an alternative.